# Java socket connects on client-side but is not accepted on server

Tags: java, sockets

I've recently started trying to create a two-way connection between a server and a client using the java Sockets class. Everything works fine (it is a chat) when I use the client socket address as `InetAddress.getLocalHost(),` but when I type in my public ip address in

```
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket(my_public_ip, 80);
```

the client socket shows that a connection is formed by testing `clientSocket.isConnected()` which returns true.

However, in the server side, the code does not seem to advance past

```
Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
```

Should I provide code or is the issue clear?

EDIT: More information. Telnet from my own pc using the external ip address works, whatever the state of my firewall. The java client-side code doesn't work when the firewall is on, throwing

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

When the firewall is off, using the java client-side code returns the following from the server (still no .accept() on server-side):

```
Connected to server. Input a message
Server: HTTP/1.0 503 unknown method
Server: Connection: close
Server: Content-Length: 119
Server: Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 12:40:00 GMT
Server: Expires: 0
Server:
Server: <html>
Server: <head><title>Error 503: unknown method</title></head>
Server: <body>
Server: <h1>Error 503: unknown method</h1>
Server: </body>
Server: </html>
```

After which both threads freeze.

Comment: What IP address is the server listening on?

Answer (score 0):

"internal_ip" doesn't sound like anybody's external IP address. Obviously you have connected to something other than your server, i.e. an HTTP server somewhere.

Comment: Ok that was a big typo. I meant that i use my public ip address and then it stops working. The client socket seems to connect but the server socket is blocked (doesnt advance past) the .accept() method. Is there something im missing?